# How to add .ts file into definitelytyped github repository?

Tags: git, typescript, definitelytyped

I cant find any proper documentation for a beginner. I dont know how to add a definition file of my company into the repository. I need step by step guidelines from the core. Please help me. What is the procedure they are following?

Comment: DefinitelyTyped has a very comprehensive guide on how to contribute definitions.

http://definitelytyped.org/guides/contributing.html

Comment: If you're just starting out you might want to look into typings instead of tsd since typings will allow you to host your definitions inside your own github project.